# websocket transport not functioning on google cloud app engine standard with NestJS (only longpolling), does work in flex environment

Tags: angular, google-cloud-platform, websocket, nestjs

I have been running a NestJS API in a Google Cloud App Engine Service for about 6 months now on the flex environment.  I'm testing in one of my lower environments on a service hosted on the standard app engine service environment and noticed today that when I establish a websocket connection from an angular front end, it only works with the longpolling transport.  In my flex environment, the websockets transport works fine.

I'm not seeing any errors on my API logging so I'm guessing the standard environment on GCP has some sort of mechanism in place that's preventing the wss traffic to connect on websockets.

It's also possible that my API just isn't logging out exceptions being thrown to the GCP logger for that event.

In the event it is something with the API is there some kind of configuration change I need to make on the API project to allow this?  Otherwise, is there something I need to change when deploying to a standard environment in GCP to allow this to work?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Websockets are only supported in Flexible (see the section - Comparing high-level features on Google's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments))

Comment: awesome, thank you for pointing to that.  We'll live with long-polling in our lower environments.  thanks again!